# Does keras_tuner BayesianOptimization warm start?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

I used a `keras_tuner.BayesianOptimization` on particular search space, and it took a while to find the best model.

I'd like to change the search space a bit but allow it to use the previous trials to chose which direction to explore it (given that the Bayesian Optimization part requires previous trials to know where to go).

Is this kind of warm start possible?